# API request in python and "Process finished with exit code 0"

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am requesting an api and get the following response and not getting my results.
For IDE I am using pycharm community edition.

```
import requests
import json

def tes():
 url="https://user-service.abc.co.in/api/user/admin/roles/"
 header ={'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
 payload ={'phone_number': '9999999999'}

 resp=requests.get(url,headers=header,data=json.dump(payload,indent=4))
 assert resp.status_code==200
 resp_body=resp.json()
 assert resp_body['url']==url
 print(resp.text)
```

Please help me why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

In the line `resp=requests.get(url,headers=header,data=json.dump(payload,indent=4))` you are trying to convert the payload to json but you called `json.dump()` which expects a file-like object as second parameter. From the docs:

`json.dump(obj, fp)`

> Serialize obj as a JSON formatted stream to fp (a .write()-supporting file-like object) [Python docs for json.dump()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump)

For your purposes you want to use `json.dumps(obj)` (notice the 's' at the end) which

> Serialize obj to a JSON formatted str
>   [Python docs for json.dumps()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps)